# How to swipe images left and right when it is popped up to a large image

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, gesture

I have written the code to swipe an image in the gallery app. When it is popped up to a large image,I want to swipe the images left and right and written the following code.But its still not working.Can anybody suggest whats wrong with the code?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 self.imageview.image = self.Image


  var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
        var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))


        leftSwipe.direction = .Left
        rightSwipe.direction = .Right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}

 func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .Left){
            self.imageview.image = self.Image
        }

        if (sender.direction == .Right){
            self.imageview.image = self.Image
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**handleSwipes** func calls *self.Image* and it is never updated since it is allocated(i.e.,self.Image one image itself ) in viewdidload.Just pass different image for left and right swipe Just pass different image in left and right swipe.                                                      if (sender.direction == .Left){
            self.imageview.image = self.Image
        }

```
    if (sender.direction == .Right){
        self.imageview.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png");
    }
```

Comment: What should be the return type for the function SwipeGestureRecognizer once it is called in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have an array of `UIImage`s called `imagesArray`

```
var currentIndex = 0{
   didSet{
     self.imageview.image = imagesArray[currentIndex]
   }
} // instance variable

func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) 
{
   if (sender.direction == .Left)
   {
       if currentIndex < imagesArray.count - 1
       {
          currentIndex++
       }
   }
   else
   {
        if currentIndex > 0
        {
           currentIndex--
        }
   }
}
```